# How write some html code inside a listing block in asciiDoctor?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

It is possible to add dome html code inside a listing block?

I have a file like:

```
----
Blablabla
+++<b>This has to be interpreted as HTML</b>+++
<span>This has not to be interpreted as HTML but as TEXT</span>
----
```

This is printed so:

```
Blablabla
+++<b>This has to be interpreted as HTML</b>+++
<span>This has not to be interpreted as HTML but as TEXT</span>
```

But it should be printed so:

```
Blablabla
This has to be interpreted as HTML
<span>This has not to be interpreted as HTML but as TEXT</span>
```

Somebody has an idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code blocks disable most Asciidoctor substitutions by default. But you can control which substitutions should be enabled for any specific block.

For your example, add the `[source,subs="+macros"]` line before your code block:

```
[source,subs="+macros"]
----
Blablabla
+++<b>This has to be interpreted as HTML</b>+++
<span>This has not to be interpreted as HTML but as TEXT</span>
----
```

For more information on substitutions, see: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#subs

Especially: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#applying-substitutions